# DNS resolution slow, ping domain slow, ping ip fast, nslookup fast

Tags: internet, dns, ping

I have a problem with my laptop with Windows 7 installed, and I'm not sure how to go around finding the cause of this. Everything works fine on another laptop with Windows 7.

I've noticed that websites started loading slow. So I did

```
ping google.com
```

It took at least half a minute (maybe a minute) to resolve the IP and start to ping. The ping itself was very fast. When I pinged google's IP:

```
ping 209.85.148.100
```

It was blazing fast. When I did

```
nslookup google.com
```

The response was instantaneous.

I tried disabling other adapters, tried connecting straight to the cable, without the router in between, tried providing DNS server IP addresses manually, tried ipconfig /flushdns, ipconfig /release, ipconfig /renew, tried [disabling IPv6](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=929852). Did Spybot Search&Destroy, CCleaner, Registry Mechanic, Avast scans and cleanups.

Nothing works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, disabling IPv6 with a fix provided here: http://support.microsoft.com/?id=929852 helped. I just forgot to restart the computer after applying the fix and didn't notice any difference. I tried enabling IPv6 back with a fix from the same URL, just to make sure that it was really IPv6 which was causing the lag. Anyone care to provide more information on why?

Answer (score -1):

Check what you are using for your DNS servers. Under ipv4 properties try setting them to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. you got faster lookup most likely due to your machine caching the lookup.