# DNS resolution slow, ping domain slow, ping ip fast, nslookup fast v2

Tags: networking, dns, ipv6

When using ping while on the university network, I get DNS resolution and ping to take a very long time (around a minute), while pinging IP and calling nslookup are very fast.

I followed the advice on [DNS resolution slow, ping domain slow, ping ip fast, nslookup fast](https://superuser.com/questions/421163/dns-resolution-slow-ping-domain-slow-ping-ip-fast-nslookup-fast) to disable IPv6 and it solved the problem.

My question is if turning off IPv6 the only solution and if the problem is with my settings, or is it with the university configuration. I do not have any problem on any other network beside the university one. The problem occurs both on wireless and wired connections.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running nslookup *against each server specifically.*

One problem with bare nslookup is that it does not follow the same DNS server selection logic as Windows itself; rather, it just looks at the *first* server in the list and always uses that. So if you have multiple servers (which you most likely do, some of them IPv4 and some IPv6) and the 2nd or 3rd is failing, basic nslookup will never reveal this.

So instead of that, you should first run `ipconfig /all` or `Get-DnsClientServerAddress | fl` to see *all* DNS servers that are configured on your machine, then run `nslookup` against every one of them individually. For example:

```
nslookup <domain> <server_to_query>

nslookup google.com 10.147.10.53
nslookup google.com 2001:db8:e27f::53
nslookup google.com fe80::c5c2:73e2:5a83

# Also test Google's and Cloudflare's v4 and v6 servers to be sure:
nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8
nslookup google.com 2001:4860:4860::8888
nslookup google.com 1.1.1.1
nslookup google.com 2606:4700:4700::1111
```

One of them will likely turn out to be inaccessible, and there could be a few possible causes.

- One of them is that you had an unreachable address configured statically (in Windows' IPv6 protocol settings) – and either the address is outright wrong, or outdated, or has been blocked by the university's network admins, or something like that.

  (For example, some universities block third-party DNS servers such as Google DNS in order to impose filtering, legally-mandated or otherwise.)
- The address might be unreachable because you have a VPN active. University-provided DNS servers would be reachable only from the university, not externally (going through a VPN definitely counts as "externally").
- The address might be outdated. In Windows, if the DNS server was acquired dynamically through DHCPv6 or RDNSS, in some cases it might *stick* even after it's no longer relevant. (This does not affect DHCP via IPv4 – only IPv6 DNS servers tend to stick.)

  For example, after moving my laptop from one Wi-Fi network to another, the old IPv6 DNS servers that had been advertised by the previous network were supposed to go away – yet they didn't, and I had to manually purge them from the Registry.

  So if the address is there but shouldn't be, try opening Regedit at:

  ```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters\Interfaces
  ```

  The registry subkeys (subfolders) underneath "Interfaces" represent your network adapters; sometimes you have to delete the `NameServer` values found therein. (Deleting all those settings under "Interfaces" is safe... as long as you look carefully *what and where* you're deleting.)
- Finally, it is possible that you simply *do not have IPv6 access* on this particular network. This might be caused by the network itself, or by an installed firewall, or even by a VPN client.

  (Many paid-VPN services block IPv6, because they think that's the easiest way to prevent "IPv6 leaks" – rather than just... supporting IPv6. Unfortunately, some of them implement this block so well that it stays around even if you disconnect from the VPN.)

#### That didn't help

If you've tested every single server and they seem to be fine, the problem might be not DNS but one of the *local* name lookup protocols, such as LLMNR or mDNS.

Those are multicast-based; there is no central place which could give a definite negative answer – instead Windows has to wait a few seconds before it can declare the name "not found".

This and probably all other possible causes can be determined by using packet capture tools to actually *look at what's happening* under the hood. On Windows, one such tool is [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). (Microsoft has its own "Network Monitor" but I'm not sure where to obtain it.)

Make sure to run it against each network interface – in particular, if you have something like a "VirtualBox Host-only Network", Windows could be sending mDNS/LLMNR queries in there as well, so it's not enough to only look at the main "Wi-Fi" interface.